# Auto Layout issue with embed UIViewController inside UIView

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiviewcontroller, autolayout

My code works fine, and I've successfully embedded a UIViewController within UIView. The auto-layout from small to full screen and exiting full screen worked perfectly with just UIView, but when UIViewController was added inside the UIView, entering full screen was fine, it worked smoothly, but when exiting the screen, it did not function well. Is there anything I missed?

Here my code:

```
    func createMainController() {
        mainControllerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        mainControllerView.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0, alpha: 0.5)
        mainControllerView.layer.cornerRadius = 25
        mainControllerView.layer.cornerCurve = .continuous
        mainControllerView.layer.maskedCorners = [.layerMinXMinYCorner, .layerMinXMaxYCorner]
        mainControllerView.clipsToBounds = true
        view.addSubview(mainControllerView)
        
        mainControllerLayout_top = mainControllerView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor)
        mainControllerLayout_top_short = mainControllerView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 60)
        mainControllerLayout_left = mainControllerView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor)
        mainControllerLayout_left_short = mainControllerView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: appTitle.trailingAnchor, constant: 40)
        mainControllerLayout_bottom = mainControllerView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor)
        mainControllerLayout_bottom_short = mainControllerView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: -60)
        mainControllerLayout_right = mainControllerView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor)
        
        mainControllerLayout_top_short?.isActive = true
        mainControllerLayout_left_short?.isActive = true
        mainControllerLayout_bottom_short?.isActive = true
        mainControllerLayout_top?.isActive = false
        mainControllerLayout_left?.isActive = false
        mainControllerLayout_bottom?.isActive = false
        mainControllerLayout_right?.isActive = true
    }
    
    @objc func fullController() {
        mainControllerLayout_top_short?.isActive = false
        mainControllerLayout_left_short?.isActive = false
        mainControllerLayout_bottom_short?.isActive = false
        mainControllerLayout_top?.isActive = true
        mainControllerLayout_left?.isActive = true
        mainControllerLayout_bottom?.isActive = true
        mainControllerLayout_right?.isActive = true
        
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 1, initialSpringVelocity: 1, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations: {
            mainControllerView.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0, alpha: 1)
            mainControllerView.layer.cornerRadius = 0
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        })
    }
    
    @objc func shortController() {
        mainControllerLayout_top_short?.isActive = true
        mainControllerLayout_left_short?.isActive = true
        mainControllerLayout_bottom_short?.isActive = true
        mainControllerLayout_top?.isActive = false
        mainControllerLayout_left?.isActive = false
        mainControllerLayout_bottom?.isActive = false
        mainControllerLayout_right?.isActive = true
        
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 1, initialSpringVelocity: 1, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations: {
            mainControllerView.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0, alpha: 0.5)
            mainControllerView.layer.cornerRadius = 25
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        })
    }
    
    func embed(_ viewController: UIViewController, inView view: UIView) {
        viewController.willMove(toParent: self)
        viewController.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(viewController.view)
        self.addChild(viewController)
        viewController.didMove(toParent: self)
        
        viewController.view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
        viewController.view.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        viewController.view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        viewController.view.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    }
    
    @objc func enterFeature() {
        fullController()
    }
    
    @objc func exitFeature() {
        shortController()
    }
```

Comment: Could you provide a gif/video to show the current issue?

Comment: Have you tried to trigger a re-layout of the view controller's own view in `viewLayoutMarginsDidChange`?

Comment: Mamta - sure, I will try if I have time.

Comment: valeCocoa - I did, nothing happened

Comment: Hey, I found issue...I simply need use button to exit from main uiviewcontroller, not inside other uiviewcontroller, for example, nav bar item. Thank you for trying.